# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I've an issue while compiling my vue project, i can't compile with this error message, i've try to update npm and webpack but it does'nt work.

```
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:8:45)
    at ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (http://localhost:8081/js/app.js:30:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8081/js/app.js:244:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:8081/js/app.js:501:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:5:213)
    at ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (http://localhost:8081/js/app.js:129:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8081/js/app.js:244:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:8081/js/app.js:501:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/components/HelloWorld.vue:3:97)
    at ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue (http://localhost:8081/js/app.js:107:1)
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-axios": "^3.5.2",
    "vue-loader": "^17.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

And this is my helloworld.vue

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

export default {
 name: 'HelloWorld',
 mounted(){
   Vue.axios.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=c9723e0fa4f3491bba98d4f04a8d0163')
   .then((resp)=>{
     console.warn(resp)
   })
 }
 // props: {
 //   msg: String
 // },

}
</script>
```

i've try to delete node_modules folder & package_lock.json and reinstalling npm-install but did'nt work, my node version is 16.16.0

Comment: So, what does `HelloWorld.vue` contain? We can't help you fix this error without your code.

Comment: i'm sure you are on vue 3 or at least vue e2.7 or later global installation of lplugin is not allowed use `createApp().use`

Comment: im using vue cli 3

Comment: You're on Vue 3 but you've followed Vue 2 installation instructions. Consult the Vue Axios documentation for Vue 3